# Can't display values in my page ......ACF

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Hi Guys my name is Fotis and i am a junior web developer.

The reason i need your help is because i am trying to create this gallery http://www.elliotcondon.com/creating-an-image-gallery-with-advanced-custom-fields/ and i am using custom fields and the add on repeater.

But i can’t see anything on my browser and in my home page. Why this is happening ? what i am doing wrong?

Please anyone who know to help me

Thank you for reading my request!
Here is my index.php code

```
  <?php


get_header(); ?>


<div id="content">
<div id="main">







    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; else: endif; ?>

    <?php query_posts('category_name='.get_the_title().'&post_status=publish,future');?>
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
    <p><?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; else: endif; ?>



<!-- Slider -->
<?php if(get_field('images')): ?>
    <div id="slider">
        <?php while(the_repeater_field('images')): ?>
            <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_sub_field('image'), 'full'); ?>
            <?php $thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_sub_field('image'), 'thumbnail'); ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="<?php  the_sub_field('title');?>" rel="<?php echo $thumb[0]; ?>" />
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can't give you a definite answer from the provided info, but if there is a space before the opening php tag it can cause troubles. Do you get any errors when you turn on WP_DEBUG from wp-config.php ? Also, are the images set to return IDs ?

Comment: yes it was the id kaloyan thank you so much!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by making a frontpage .php ,in which you include all the index .php code.Then in settings you set front page the home page you've made and posts page the blank blog page. And so simple you can fix the problem.Here is the frontpage.php i made and i solved my problem.

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: front-page.php Template
 */

get_header(); ?>

<?php
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 10 );
$lastposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $lastposts as $post ) :
  setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php endforeach; 


//for each category, show 3 posts
$cat_args=array(
  'orderby' => 'name',
  'order' => 'ASC'
   );
$categories=get_categories($cat_args);
  foreach($categories as $category) {
    $args=array(
      'showposts' => 3,
      'category__in' => array($category->term_id),
      'caller_get_posts'=>1
    );
    $posts=get_posts($args);
      if ($posts) {
        echo '<p>Category: <a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a> </p> ';
        foreach($posts as $post) {
          setup_postdata($post); ?>
          <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
          <?php
        } // foreach($posts
      } // if ($posts
    } // foreach($categories


wp_reset_postdata();  ?>
<?php global $post;
$pid = $post->ID;
get_field('slide',$pid);
?>
<!-- Slider -->
<div class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
    <?php
    $rows = get_field('slide');
    if($rows) {

        foreach($rows as $row) {
            // retrieve size 'large' for background image
            $bgimg = $row['bg_image']['sizes']['large'];
            $output = "<li style='background-image: url(". $bgimg .");'>\n";
            $output .= "  <div class='slide-text'>\n";
            $output .= "  <h2>". $row['slide_heading'] ."</h2>\n";
            $output .= "  " . $row['slide_text'];
            $output .= "  </div>\n";
            $output .= "</li>\r\n\n";
            $output .= "  " . $row['slide_link']; 

            echo $output;
        }    
    }
    ?> 


    </ul>
</div> 



</div>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?
```

Here is the functions.php file in which you set the template for each page.

```
<?php 
/***********************************************************************************************/
/* Define Constants */
/***********************************************************************************************/
define('THEMEROOT', get_stylesheet_directory_uri());
define('IMAGES', THEMEROOT.'/images');

function register_my_menu() {
  register_nav_menu('header-menu',__( 'Header Menu' ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menu' );



// Add support for featured images
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );

function get_future_posts($post_type, $require_featured, $number_posts=1) {
    $today = current_time( 'timestamp' );
    $posts = get_posts(array(
        'posts_per_page'    => $number_posts,
        'post_type'         => $post_type,
        'meta_key'          => 'date_time',
        'meta_compare'      => '>=',
        'meta_value'        => $today,
        'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
        'order'             => 'ASC',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'featured_event',
                'value' => $require_featured
            )
        )
    ));
    return $posts;
}
add_action('init', 'my_custom_init');

function my_custom_init() {
    // remember add first parameter post type as 'page'
    add_post_type_support( 'page', 'page-attributes' );
}

 // Load our scripts
if (!is_admin()) add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "my_jquery_enqueue", 11);
function my_jquery_enqueue() {
   wp_deregister_script('jquery');
   wp_register_script('jquery', "http" . ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443 ? "s" : "") . "://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js", false, null);
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
?>
```

And of course the header.php

```
<head>
  <!-- Page Meta -->
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="<?php bloginfo('html_type') ?>; charset=<?php bloginfo('charset') ?>" />
  <title><?php wp_title( '-', true, 'right' ); echo esc_html( get_bloginfo('name'), 1 ); ?></title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url') ?>" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url') ?>/css/flexislider.css" />
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/js/jquery.flexislider.js"type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
(function($) {
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('.flexslider').flexslider({
                animation: 'slide',
            controlsContainer: '.flex-container'
        });
    });
})(jQuery)
</script>

  <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>



<nav>


<div class="container">
                <ul class="nav-list">

                    <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/Home" class="event-link">Αρχική</a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/Useful" class="event-link">Χρήσιμα</a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/Social" class="event-link">Κοινωνικά</a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/Other things" class="event-link">Διάφορα</a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/Sports" class="event-link">Αθλητικά</a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/News" class="event-link">Ειδήσεις</a></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/Events" class="event-link">Εκδηλώσεις</a></li>

                </ul>
</div>
        </nav>




    </header>
```

And finally this is the code in order to develop a flexi slider with ACF Repeater.

Enjoy!